# (How) can I use CKAN when data needs to be kept in place and only its data dictionary should be published?

Tags: metadata, ckan

#### Context

I am investigating how I can set-up a data management system for a department of 100+ colleagues.

Many of our datasets are stored (scattered is a better word) on different network drives, database instances and servers, and the organisation needs to keep it that way (for now) due to security and certification reasons.

However, the department does see the value in knowing what data exists and where it can be accessed. Because of that it's looking for a searchable data catalog method that would allow us to search the metadata of the datasets and then, use existing processes to actually request access to the data if needed.

In my ideal case:

- A data owner would use CKAN to extract a data dictionary (tables, files, columns, types) from a stored dataset (database, CSV's, etc...) without storing the data in CKAN itself.
- With that data dictionary the data admin creates a CKAN dataset with all the relevant metadata and perhaps a few data samples (e.g. first 100 rows of each table).
- The data owner adds a link to the CKAN dataset with instruction on how to request access (e.g. contact Dilbert and request read rights for network share `\\unc\path\to\data`).
- Colleagues without read rights to the dataset *can* search the metadata in CKAN and requests access to the data itself outside of CKAN.

#### Question

Will CKAN (+extensions) allow me to do the above? If so, how would that process look like roughly?
If not, is there another data cataloguing method that I can use?

#### Looked into so far

##### User manual

From the [user guide](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/user-guide.html) I see that it supports three methods to add data:

- Link to file
- Link to API
- Upload a file

It's not clear to me if any of these methods would be able to create a dataset while only reading the data once to obtain it's data dictionary.

##### Extensions

- I found the [ckanext-dataproxy](https://extensions.ckan.org/extension/dataproxy/) extension that allows one to read remote databases.
  It's unclear though if that preview can be used to extract a persistent data dictionary.
- I found the [ckanext-extractor](https://extensions.ckan.org/extension/extractor/) extension which seems to do the metadata extraction part, however the examples seem to be limited to documents (doc, pdf) and don't mention databases or CSV's.